# How can we change the chrome default download directory in Testcafe?

Tags: testing, download, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Kindly provide the steps to set the download file path in Testcafe.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find and check a downloaded file, you can use the following ways:

- Use the RequestLogger: [Check the Downloaded File Name and Content example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/check-downloaded-file-name-and-content)
- Obtain a "Downloads" folder path from the system environment variables or use the [downloads-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloads-folder) package:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import downloadsFolder from 'downloads-folder';

fixture('fixture')
    .page('http://example.com/');

test('test', async t => {
    await t.click('#download');

    const filePath = downloadsFolder() + '/my-file.txt';

    await t.expect(fs.existsSync(filePath)).ok();
});
```

Also, TestCafe internal API allows you to change the downloads path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65732040/10684943. Note that this approach is not recommended. Use it at your own risk.